# AdWhirl integration problem in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

I have to implement AdWhirl in my app. It works fine - I'm getting ads from AdMob and iAd now.

There is no ad coming from AdMod and iAd. I am getting an error in the console. I can provide the code I'm using if it'd be helpful.

Comment: <AdMob> The AdMob SDK requires a valid view controller to be returned from currentViewController (AdMobDelegateProtocol).
  Cancelling ad request.

ADBannerView: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 is deprecated, please use ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait instead

these Errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by implementing this delegate...

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView
{
    return yourAPP.viewController;
}
```